# Spawning pr2 problem (pr2_simulator)

Tags: ros, gazebo, timeout, spawn

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hello everyone,

I have problems with the pr2_simulator. I have installed it and I was following the first steps in the "Introductory Tutorials" of pr2_simulator.
I was trying to spawn the pr2 robot in a Gazebo empty world.

I had to use

```
roslaunch gazebo_ros empty_world.launch
```

instead of

```
roslaunch gazebo_worlds empty_world.launch
```

in order to launch the 3d environment. (If I remember well it's because of the newer versions of Gazebo...)

However, when I launch the command

```
roslaunch pr2_gazebo pr2.launch
```

I get an error:

```
spawn status:  SpawnModel: Model pushed to spawn queue, but spawn service timed out waiting for model to appear in simulation under the name pr2
```

What can I do? :(

Thank you in advance!

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/66287/spawning-pr2-problem-(pr2_simulator)/) by [kir](https://answers.ros.org/users/5291/kir/) on ROS Answers with karma: 23 on 2013-06-30

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi!,

I think that there is some problem with the urdf files for the pr2_robot. Probably the urdf files from the pr2_package you downloaded, are too old for the Gazebo version you are using. I think its a similar problem as the one asked here http://answers.ros.org/question/200497/cant-spawn-model-in-gazebo/

So i think the solution could be to make sure you are using the latest version of the pr2 package, and the ones that match the ubuntu version you have.

I hope this helps you!

---

Originally posted by [donmrsir](https://answers.ros.org/users/19553/donmrsir/) with karma: 363 on 2015-09-29

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0